# Not able to display selected value in drop down list in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a dropdownlist , i can see list item from 1 to 10, however when I select any one of the value it doesnt display in dropdownlist,

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlqty" runat="server" CssClass="myselect">
    <asp:ListItem Value="1" Selected="True">1</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Value="2">2</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Value="3">3</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Value="4">4</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Value="5">5</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Value="6">6</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Value="7">7</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Value="8">8</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Value="9">9</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Value="10">10</asp:ListItem>
</asp:DropDownList>
```

what am i missing here. Also when in code behind intellisense not getting `ddlqty` which is the ID of the dropdownlist.

This is the HTML I am getting from the browser:

```
 <select name="Repeater1$ctl01$ddlqty" id="Repeater1_ddlqty_0" class="myselect">
<option selected="selected" value="1">1</option>
<option value="2">2</option>
<option value="3">3</option>
<option value="4">4</option>
<option value="5">5</option>
<option value="6">6</option>
<option value="7">7</option>
<option value="8">8</option>
<option value="9">9</option>
<option value="10">10</option>
```

My `Repeater` class

```
<asp:Repeater ID="Repeater1" runat="server">
    <HeaderTemplate></HeaderTemplate>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <tr class="cart_item">
            <td class="product-thumbnail">
                <a href="#">
                    <img src=" images/ecommerce/products/hoodie_1_front-150x150.jpg" alt=""></a>
            </td>
            <td class="product-name"><a href="#"><%#Eval("ItemName") %></a>
                <dl class="variation">
                    <dt class="variation-Color">Category:</dt>
                    <dd class="variation-Color">
                        <p><%#Eval("Category") %></p>
                    </dd>
                </dl>
            </td>
            <td class="product-price"><span class="amount"><%#Eval("Rate") %></span></td>
            <td class="product-quantity">
                <%-- <a href="#" class="minus disabled">-</a>
                                    <input type="text" value="1"> <a href="#" class="plus">+</a></td>--%>
                <%--<input type="text" value="1" readonly="true">--%>

                <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlqty" runat="server" CssClass="myselect">
                    <asp:ListItem Value="1" Selected="True">1</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem Value="2">2</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem Value="3">3</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem Value="4">4</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem Value="5">5</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem Value="6">6</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem Value="7">7</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem Value="8">8</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem Value="9">9</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem Value="10">10</asp:ListItem>
                </asp:DropDownList>

                <%--<asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" runat="server" CausesValidation="false" CommandName="Edit" Text="Change" Font-Size="Small"></asp:LinkButton>--%>
                <td class="product-subtotal"><span class="amount">$ <%#Eval("Rate") %></span></td>
                <td class="product-remove"><a href="#" class="remove"><i class="fa fa-times"></i></a></td>
        </tr>
    </ItemTemplate>
    <FooterTemplate></FooterTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

Please help

Comment: Is the DropDownList inside a Repeater, GridView, ListView? If so you cannot access it directly.

Comment: yes it is inside Repeater

Comment: Can you post HTML code you are getting in the browser for this drop down list. Just for cross verification from client side.

Comment: @NaveenKN whole HTML or just from the Repeater ?

Comment: please check edit in question

Answer (score 1):

When a Control is inside a Repeater, you cannot access it directly. You will have to use `FindControl` with an Index number of the Item that contains the Control inside the Repeater.

```
DropDownList drp = Repeater1.Items[index].FindControl("ddlqty") as DropDownList;
drp.SelectedValue = "2";
```

**UPDATE**

If you want to set the DropDownList values from the cart, and update the cart when you change the items you can do this by adding `OnItemDataBound` and `OnSelectedIndexChanged`

```
<asp:Repeater ID="Repeater1" runat="server" OnItemDataBound="Repeater1_ItemDataBound">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlqty" runat="server" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlqty_SelectedIndexChanged" AutoPostBack="true">
            <asp:ListItem Value="1">1</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Value="2">2</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Value="3">3</asp:ListItem>
        </asp:DropDownList>
        <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("tocht_id") %>' Visible="false"></asp:Label>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

Code behind

```
protected void Repeater1_ItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
{
    int itemsInCart = 3;

    //find the dropdownlist using findcontrol
    DropDownList drp = e.Item.FindControl("ddlqty") as DropDownList;

    //set the correct cart value
    drp.SelectedValue = itemsInCart.ToString();
}

protected void ddlqty_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //cast the sender back to a dropdownlist
    DropDownList drp = sender as DropDownList;

    //get the item as a repeater item
    RepeaterItem item = drp.NamingContainer as RepeaterItem;

    //find the label with the product ID in the Repeater
    Label lbl = Repeater1.Items[item.ItemIndex].FindControl("Label1") as Label;

    //get the product id from the attri
    int productID = Convert.ToInt32(lbl.Text);

    //convert the selectedvalue back to an int
    int itemsInCart = Convert.ToInt32(drp.SelectedValue);

    //you now have the product id and the new cart amount
}
```

Comment: I wrote in `Page_Load` and getting error on index, do I have to delare it? Sorry if I am sounding very amateur

Comment: The index is the x item in the Repeater after you have bound data to it. So if you have 5 items in the Repeater and you want to access the third item's dropdownlist, you use index = 2

Comment: I have posted my repeater if you could please look at it and tell me Index that would be great help. As per me I am putting but it gives e error `Index was out of range`

Comment: I can't tell you the index, it depends on the data you will bind to it and for which item you want to access the DropDownList

Comment: Note that the index is an array, so the first item is `0`. If you are trying to access an item that is greater that the total items you'll get the index out of range error

Comment: @mark you wan to select dropdown at the time of page load? I guess you are trying to bind cart details right?

Comment: @KevinShah yes I want to update amount based on the quantity selected

Comment: you basically first bind repeater from database and then after you want to allow user to select quantity and then change amount based on qty

Comment: I am getting data in repeater from cookies

Answer (score 1):

Try to get the `DropDownList` value using `foreach` loop

```
foreach(RepeaterItem item in rpt1.Items)
{
   DropDownList ddl = (DropDownList)item.FindControl("ddl");
   string ddl_value = ddl.SelectedValue;               
}
```

**Note: rpt1 is Repeater's Id**

> also note that by using `foreach loop` you'll get all `dropdownlist's`
>   value, so you have to use it according your scenario.

Comment: I can see values in dropdownlist, however when I click any of the numbers it doesnt show as selected value in dropdownlist it self

Comment: Nothing its blank

Comment: @mark please make sure your `DropDownList's` css work fine, i mean it does not affecting the text in `dropdownlist`, not sure but could be the reason.

Comment: I am usiing dropdownlist directly in aspx page not through css

Answer (score 0):

Below is the code that will use to Bind Repeater at page load under IsPostback condition on page load event

```
 private void BindData()
        {
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            dt.Columns.Add("ID", Type.GetType("System.String"));
            dt.Columns.Add("ItemName", Type.GetType("System.String"));
            dt.Columns.Add("Category", Type.GetType("System.String"));
            dt.Columns.Add("Rate", Type.GetType("System.String"));
            dt.Columns.Add("Qty", Type.GetType("System.String"));
            dt.Columns.Add("Total", Type.GetType("System.String"));
            for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++)
            {
                DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();
                dr["ID"] = 1;
                dr["ItemName"] = "hoodie";
                dr["Category"] = "Hoodie";
                dr["Rate"] = 25;
                dr["Qty"] = 4;
                dr["Total"] = (4 * 25);
                dt.Rows.Add(dr);
            }
            Repeater1.DataSource = dt;
            Repeater1.DataBind();
        }



        protected void Repeater1_ItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item || e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem)
            {
                DropDownList ddlQty = new DropDownList();
                ddlQty = (DropDownList)e.Item.FindControl("ddlqty");
                HiddenField hdn = new HiddenField();
                hdn = (HiddenField)e.Item.FindControl("hdnQty");
                if (hdn.Value != "")
                {
                    ddlQty.SelectedItem.Selected = false;
                    ddlQty.Items.FindByValue(hdn.Value).Selected = true;
                }
            }
        }
```

You need to use ItemDataBound event of Repeater that will give you control at the time of binding data to repeater and you can change value of that control while binding records.

Another thing that you have to do is to handle dropdown selected index event that will give you value of qty and you can use it to rebind repeater.

Comment: hi, Sorry for delay repsonse, I tried this code i got error at `if (hdn.Value != "")` that `Object reference not set to an instance of an object.`

Comment: and why are we using HiddenField ?

Comment: just to store intial value of Qty that user has selected so based on that value on ItemDataBound event we can set that to Dropdown

Comment: Also you have to put that field in your Repeater control as well in itemTemplate

Comment: dropdown list is already there but in Dropdown list there is not any property using which we can directly select it value while binding repeater so for that I have used hidden field in which I am storing actual quantity and in ItemDataBound finding that dropdown and select its value with hidden field value.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/143299/discussion-between-kevin-shah-and-mark).

Answer (score 0):

I am able to solve my issue, now i can see selected value in the text of dropdownlist. However i have to remove `Repeater`. And used gridview instead. I am having 1 issue that when I click on `Save` using `<asp:LinkButton ID="lnkUpdate" runat="server" CommandName="Update" Text="Save" ></asp:LinkButton>` it refreshes the page and value again goes to 1 which is by default value.
Heres my code:

```
 <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" CellPadding="4" DataKeyNames="slno" ForeColor="#333333" GridLines="None" HorizontalAlign="Center" Width="100%" OnRowEditing="GridView1_RowEditing" OnRowCancelingEdit="GridView1_RowCancelingEdit" OnRowUpdating="GridView1_RowUpdating">
     <RowStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" VerticalAlign="Middle" BackColor="#F7F6F3" ForeColor="#333333" />
      <Columns>
      <asp:BoundField DataField="slno" HeaderText="Sl No" ReadOnly="true">
         <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" VerticalAlign="Middle" />
           <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" VerticalAlign="Middle" />
      </asp:BoundField>
      <asp:BoundField DataField="itemname" HeaderText="Item Name" ReadOnly="true">
         <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Left" VerticalAlign="Middle" />
           <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Left" VerticalAlign="Middle" />
      </asp:BoundField>
     <asp:BoundField DataField="Rate" HeaderText="Price" ReadOnly="true">
         <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" VerticalAlign="Middle" />
           <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" VerticalAlign="Middle" />
     </asp:BoundField>
  <asp:TemplateField HeaderStyle-CssClass="headerStyle" HeaderText="Quantity">
     <EditItemTemplate>
         <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlqty" runat="server" DataTextField='<%# Bind("qty") %>' AutoPostBack="false" EnableViewState="true">

             <asp:ListItem>1</asp:ListItem>

             <asp:ListItem>2</asp:ListItem>

             <asp:ListItem>3</asp:ListItem>

             <asp:ListItem>4</asp:ListItem>

             <asp:ListItem>5</asp:ListItem>
                                                                                                                 </asp:DropDownList>
   </EditItemTemplate>

   <ItemTemplate>
     <asp:Label ID="lblqty" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("qty") %>'></asp:Label>
   </ItemTemplate>

   <HeaderStyle CssClass="headerStyle" HorizontalAlign="Center" VerticalAlign="Middle" />
     <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" VerticalAlign="Middle" />
</asp:TemplateField>
   <asp:TemplateField HeaderStyle-CssClass="headerStyle">
                                                <EditItemTemplate>
                                                    <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkUpdate" runat="server" CommandName="Update" Text="Save" ></asp:LinkButton>
                                                    <%--<asp:LinkButton ID="lnkCancel" runat="server" CommandName="Cancel" Text="Cancel"></asp:LinkButton>--%>
                                                </EditItemTemplate>
                                                <ItemTemplate>
                                                    <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" runat="server" CausesValidation="false" CommandName="Edit" Text="Change"></asp:LinkButton>
                                                </ItemTemplate>
                                                <HeaderStyle CssClass="headerStyle" />
                                                <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" Width="30px" Font-Size="Small" />
                                            </asp:TemplateField>
                                            <asp:BoundField DataField="total" HeaderText="Total" ReadOnly="true">
                                                <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Right" VerticalAlign="Middle" />
                                                <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Right" VerticalAlign="Middle" />
                                            </asp:BoundField>
                                        </Columns>
                                        <EditRowStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" VerticalAlign="Middle" BackColor="#999999" />
                                        <FooterStyle BackColor="#5D7B9D" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
                                        <PagerStyle BackColor="#284775" ForeColor="White" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                                        <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#E2DED6" ForeColor="#333333" Font-Bold="True" />
                                        <HeaderStyle BackColor="#5D7B9D" Font-Bold="True" HorizontalAlign="Center" VerticalAlign="Middle" ForeColor="White" />
                                        <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" ForeColor="#284775" />
                                        <SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor="#E9E7E2" />
                                        <SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#506C8C" />
                                        <SortedDescendingCellStyle BackColor="#FFFDF8" />
                                        <SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#6F8DAE" />
                                    </asp:GridView>
```

I had a previous project with me doen by a friend so used his codes.